# petrol station filled tank

Tags: mathematical-statistics

At a petrol station, 90% of the customers use RON95 fuel, 5% use RON97
fuel and 5% use diesel fuel. Suppose that 75%, 80% and 90% of RON95
users, RON97 users and diesel users fill their tanks, respectively. At this
station, a customer just filled her tank. What is the probability that she used
RON95 fuel?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Suppose there are $1000$ customers:

- How many do you expect to use RON95? How many do you expect to use RON95 and fill their tanks?
- How many do you expect to use RON97? How many do you expect to use RON97 and fill their tanks?
- How many do you expect to use diesel? How many do you expect to use diesel and fill their tanks?
- How many in total do you expect to fill their tanks?
- What proportion of those filling their tanks do you do you expect to use RON95 and fill their tanks?